# animate a texture according to the position of an object

Tags: animation, texturing, materials

I'm on a really difficult project and I'm blocking on one thing.
I have many simulated soft bodies that are projected on the ceiling and crushed.

I'm looking to change the texture of the object when it crashes. It should be automated in the animation so as not to do it by hand for each object.

I think to use a collider (or empty), when the object crosses its texture changes, but i'm not sure if it's possible.

[image]

It's a cell simulation, when the top cells are crushed, i want the core outline disappears, so only the core remains.
If i just anime the texture or material, all cells are affected.

This is a example what it should look like :

[image]

Thx all

Comment: I think this very question has been asked this week, but I can't find it. The texture coordinate node in the shader editor has an object field, which can be used to input the position of another object

Comment: Could you be more specific about  'change the texture'? .. you might be interested in a [tension map](https://github.com/ScottishCyclops/tensionmap).. original description with broken links [here](https://youtu.be/6G8SkBQngvw)

Comment: Thx Gorgious, that's what i try to do with an object field or a box collider but i don't found in 2.81.

Comment: interesting the tension map plugin I keep it on hand, to animate the whole material is easier I don't think I need as much.